# How to pull a value from between 2 strings which occur several times in a file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to pull the value from inbetween 2 strings and line break each result. I am then hoping to combine this with another value from the same document being pulled the same way. The problem is there are NO linebreaks in this file and it is quite large. Here is an example of the file.

```
<ID>47</ID><DATACENTER_ID>36</DATACENTER_ID><DNS_NAME>myhost.domain.local</DNS_NAME>      <IP_ADDRESS>10.0.0.1</IP_ADDRESS><ID>60</ID><DATACENTER_ID>36</DATACENTER_ID><DNS_NAME>yourhost.domain.local</DNS_NAME><IP_ADDRESS>10.0.0.2</IP_ADDRESS>
```

My end result would ideally look something like this.

```
ID-----DNS_NAME
47-----myhost.domain.local
60-----yourhost.domain.local
```

My closest attemps so far have been creating variables with grep, but I cant seem to format them into a table. Im also very new to scripting so forgive my ignorance.

Comment: XML parsing using basic shell utilities should be avoided Use a dedicated XML parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your grep supports `-P` (`--Perl-regexp`), then you're free to use the below regex.

```
$ grep -oP '<ID>\K[^<>]*(?=</ID>)|<DNS_NAME>\K[^<>]*(?=</DNS_NAME>)' file | sed 'N;s/\n/-----/g'
47-----myhost.domain.local
60-----yourhost.domain.local
```

`\K` Discards the previously matched characters from printing.

`(?=...)` posiitve lookahead assertion which asserts where the match would occur. It won't consume any characters.

Comment: Good use of `grep -o`! My only curiosity would be how the `grep/sed` combination compares from an efficiency standpoint to a duel expression `sed` (e.g. `sed -e exp1 exp2 file`) solution. Regardless, good answer.

Comment: Thanks Avinash, That's perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `gnu awk` (do to multiple characters in `RS`) to get your data:

```
awk -v RS="<ID>" -F"<|>" 'NR>1 {print $1"-----"$9}' file
47-----myhost.domain.local
60-----yourhost.domain.local
```

Comment: This is also very handy! Thank you much Jotne.